# How i can calculate the size of any class in Java?

Tags: java

```
class Abc {

}
```

Suppose this is my class and I want to know the size the of that class. How can I calculate the size of a class created in Java. Even if I create an object of that particular class.

Comment: give an example. its unclear what you're asking.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Java, what is the best way to determine the size of an object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52353/in-java-what-is-the-best-way-to-determine-the-size-of-an-object)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11252249/calculating-weight-of-an-object-howto That is what you need, assuming you talk about the memory cost an object has.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know the memory size of the files you've created, you can go to your project's folder directory. 
There, in "src" folder, you can right-click any .java file and see its size. In the "bin" folder, there are also the binary .class files. 
Feel free to compare them.

Comment: if i had a multiple classes iin my one .java file then it will vary .

Comment: I want to find the class size in memory when  object is created.